# New relic not recording curl calls to web services?

Tags: php, curl, newrelic

I have a PHP application running on multiple server behind load balancer which interacts with multiple web services via curl.

I have new relic module installed on all servers but I don't see any traces of these services in new relic. Ideally it should show different metrics etc.

However new relic shows all data for controllers etc but ignores curl api calls info.

Do I need to make in config changes in new relic module to make it work?

Let me know if more info is needed.

Comment: This question is probably better directed at New Relic support. There may a more complex issue going on here.

Answer (score 0):

How are the curl commands being made?  Calls using 'curl_multi_exec' are not supported by the New Relic agent.  'curl_exec' is however. Cross process metrics and cross application tracing may not work for some uses of 'curl_exec'.

As indicated earlier, a support request to New Relic might be in order.